# syslog-ng on Solaris 10 (how to install and configure)

Tags: solaris-10, syslog-ng

If anyone has got syslog-ng working on Solaris 10, do you have a set of instructions I could follow to get it installed and working?

I tried following this http://opensystems.wordpress.com/2006/06/01/replacing-syslog-on-solaris-10-with-syslog-ng/ but got stuck with the syslog-ng service stuck restarting with no indication of why.

Thanks for any help.
NickB

Comment: Can you post the result of svcs -x ?

Comment: NDBCA2:/var/adm# svcs -x
svc:/site/system-log-ng:default (system log ng)
 State: maintenance since Tue Jan 26 09:38:44 2010
Reason: Restarting too quickly.
   See: http://sun.com/msg/SMF-8000-L5
   See: syslog-ng(1M)
   See: /var/svc/log/site-system-log-ng:default.log
Impact: This service is not running.
NDBCA2:/var/adm#

Comment: Maybe a problem with the /usr/local/etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf file?  permissions look OK - root:root and -rw-r--r--

Comment: And the linked log file has this (repeated)

syslog service starting.
[ Jan 26 09:38:44 Method "start" exited with status 0 ]
[ Jan 26 09:38:44 Stopping because all processes in service exited. ]
[ Jan 26 09:38:44 Executing stop method (:kill) ]
[ Jan 26 09:38:44 Restarting too quickly, changing state to maintenance ]

Comment: Have you tried starting things up manually, in the same way that is being done by SMF? You might get some error message clues as to why syslog-ng is exiting.

Answer (score 4):

I do not like the instructions on the opensystems blog you pointed to, as it replaces the default service in SMF. This is bad as it is likely that a future system patch will revert your changes. Here's my take on it, from a default system state:

1. Disable the system syslog:
   svcadm disable system-log
2. Download and install (using pkgadd) syslog-ng from sunfreeware.com
   http:// sunfreeware.com/programlistintel10.html#syslogng
   Do not forget to also download and install its dependencies.
3. Create a configuration file /usr/local/etc/syslog-ng.conf (the one offered on the Open Systems blog is a good start).
4. Setup the SMF voodoo:

   - Create /var/svc/manifest/site/syslog-ng.xml from http://pastebin.com/QrGC3u6p (I could not paste the file here as the formatting was mangled)
   - Load the new service: `svccfg import /var/svc/manifest/site/syslog-ng.xml`
   - Enable the service: `svcadm enable syslog-ng`

Now, your system is not vanilla if you followed the procedure on Open Systems blog. Here's what you need to do to revert:

1. Disable the modified SMF service:

   - svcadm disable system-log-ng
   - svccfg delete system-log-ng
2. Remove the syslopg-ng package

   - pkgrm NCsysng
3. Re-import the original system log service:

   - svccfg import /var/svc/manifest/system/system-log.xml
   - svcadm enable system-log

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

https://lists.balabit.hu/pipermail/syslog-ng/2005-June/007531.html

http://www.swissunixsupport.com/syslog-ngsoalris10

should help you out.